# Error: Can't resolve all parameters for ProductsEffects: (?, ?)

Tags: angular, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

I'm running Angular 9, with `@ngrx/store` v9, and with SSR, but I'm just running `npm start` in development, so SSR isn't really a factor.

I just added NGRX Store and made my actions, reducers and effects for some products. Upon running this, I now get the error: `Error: Can't resolve all parameters for ProductsEffects: (?, ?).`

The ProductsEffects class constructor is as follows:

```ts
constructor(private actions$: Actions<ProductsActions>,
            private appService: AppService) {
}
```

The AppService class is marked as `@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})`, and `actions$` should be injected from NGRX Store.

Here's the imports section from `app.module`:

```ts
const EFFECTS = [ProductsEffects];

...

imports: [
        BrowserModule.withServerTransition({appId: 'my-app'}),
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        NgxSpinnerModule,
        AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
            apiKey: 'redacted'
        }),
        SharedModule,
        routing,
        StoreModule.forRoot(reducers, {
            metaReducers,
            runtimeChecks: {
                strictStateImmutability: true,
                strictActionImmutability: true
            }
        }),
        EffectsModule.forRoot(EFFECTS),
        StoreRouterConnectingModule.forRoot()
    ],
```

Here's the relevant section from `package.json`:

```json
"@ngrx/effects": "^9.0.0",
"@ngrx/entity": "^9.0.0",
"@ngrx/router-store": "^9.0.0",
"@ngrx/store": "^9.0.0",
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue was I had forgotton to decorate the `ProductsEffects` class with `@Injectable()`.